# Web Page Won't Scroll Vertically on Screens Wider than 768px

Tags: css, scroll

I have searched, but not found what must be an obvious answer to someone who understands better than I do.

Simple problem:  this page won't scroll vertically when viewed on screen wider than 768px:
http://deaconsofdeadwood.com/photos/

On screens wider than 768px, the page is stuck in this position:
[image]

I have been picking at it awhile, using firebug and experimenting.  Not even going to tell you the weirdest part.

Two goals here:

1. Find what is wrong and a fix for the scrolling not working on screens wider than 768px.
2. Learn something, so I can find this kind of fix on my own.

Comment: Put your code here please. Thanks.

Comment: There is a lot of code on that page.  It's all visible through a browser and firebug.  Not sure how I can post it all here.

Comment: You have error in wp html output - section crackbar appears two times only on this page (view source) - try to fix it, and check then... <section id="crackbar" class="container no_clone section-crackbar  fixed-top fix">  - this part causes problem, probably...

Comment: Thank you, I will be coming back to make this fix a little later.  Very much appreciate the help I am getting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is causing the problem.

```
.section-crackbar.fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
}
```

remove fixed position and it should scroll fine. Instead use this

```
.inside.clearfix {
   position: fixed;
   left: 20%;
}
```

NOTE: I'd consider giving header a better classname.

Comment: That's the ticket!  Thank you!  I knew it had to be something simple.  Looking now to see why the problem disappears when the screen is narrower.

Comment: It will fix problem, but it will cause other, too - now you don't have fixed navigation bar on pages...

Comment: No worries we can always find a solution. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @LokeshSuthar, i think that cause of problem is element you targeted, but, not his css - rather invalid HTML is in question - same element appears two times on page, causing big mess later - check source and you will see...

Comment: yes, this html error appears only on 'photos' page and i am almost sure it is source of problems...

Comment: Changing the markup is the ultimate solution but again what I provided is the cause of current problem

Comment: Lokesh, putting up the edited solution now.  Give me a couple minutes.  As for the markup, I know I have a mess on my hands.  Will be working it through for overall quality improvement.  For now, just trying to keep it from being flagrantly broken.  The scrolling problem is one I created, when I put in a temporary fix for menus, which were disappearing on narrow screens (phones and tablets).  The menus don't do that anymore, but they still are lame.

Comment: Lokesh, maybe I did it wrong.  I tried putting up the edited solution, but now the scrolling is broken again.  Leaving it broken, pending further comments.

Comment: I just checked. '.section-crackbar.fixed-top {
position: fixed;
}' appeared again at line 10777 in pagelinesCompiled.css

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the edited solution. How does it look now?

Comment: Looks good to me. I would suggested a background to the nav with subtle opacity.

Answer (score 1):

This must be because there is no content at the side parts. Browsers don't take into account the background image's size to make the screen scrollable, only HTML contents.